# Permission denied error while executing wercker.yml

Tags: wercker

A sample github repository is linked to app.wercker.com as given in the dochttp://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/quickstarts/deployment/kubernetes

while executing the build from wercker.yml (through app.wercker.com), below error is seen.  Permission denied for "create_cities-controller.json.sh".  Please help me resolve this issue.

```
export WERCKER_STEP_ROOT="/pipeline/script-aa48a107-200c-450a-8f81-24e32622a13f"
export WERCKER_STEP_ID="script-aa48a107-200c-450a-8f81-24e32622a13f"
export WERCKER_STEP_OWNER="wercker"
export WERCKER_STEP_NAME="script"
export WERCKER_REPORT_NUMBERS_FILE="/report/script-aa48a107-200c-450a-8f81-24e32622a13f/numbers.ini"
export WERCKER_REPORT_MESSAGE_FILE="/report/script-aa48a107-200c-450a-8f81-24e32622a13f/message.txt"
export WERCKER_REPORT_ARTIFACTS_DIR="/report/script-aa48a107-200c-450a-8f81-24e32622a13f/artifacts"
source "/pipeline/script-aa48a107-200c-450a-8f81-24e32622a13f/run.sh" < /dev/null
/pipeline/script-aa48a107-200c-450a-8f81-24e32622a13f/run.sh: line 2: ./create_cities-controller.json.sh: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your pipeline is trying to execute the file `create_cities-controller.json.sh` but you do not have permission to execute it.  This could be for a variety of reasons.  The most common two would be:

- the box that you are using has its "user" set to a user that does not have execute permission on that file.  You can check the user using the `docker inspect box:tag` command (using the details of the box you used in your `wercker.yml`
- the file might not have its execute bit turned on - this can often happen when using git on windows for example - in this case you need to make sure you tell git to set the exec bit using this command: 
  `git update-index --chmod=+x ./create_cities-controller.json.sh`  (I am assuming this file comes from your source code repository - if not, then you would have to change it in the image itself, i.e. start a container from the image, do a chmod to fix it, then commit that container to update the docker image)